# In Jsp page i don't want to show those check box which are not checked whose value are coming from bean

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

Suppose I have 3 check boxes: `struts2, sql, jquery.` My bean name: `Bean`

In JS:

`for(x in data.Beans ){$('#'+data.Beans [x].check).attr('checked',true);}`

In JSP:

```
checkbox id="struts2"   name="Beans.struts2" /><br>
checkbox id="jsp"  name="Beans.sql" /><br>
checkbox id="jquery"  name="Beans.jquery" /><br>
```

Suppose `struts2` and `jQuery` value is checked so I want to show these two check boxes only in the JSP page.

How is this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSTL to do an if checked then display checked, otherwise display unchecked.

[JSTL Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html)

Comment: Doesn't Struts2 have its own tags for it?